# General Linear Group over the quaternions is a topological group

Tags: abstract-algebra, topological-groups, quaternions

How to show that General Linear Group over the quaternions is a a topological group?

Comment: What is the definition of a topological group?  Can you show that the general linear group over the quaternions satisfies all the necessary requirements?  Are you having trouble showing that the elements have inverses, perhaps?

Comment: If we use the [matrix representation of the quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations), we can think of this group as a subgroup of a larger general linear group over $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sorry, that I didn't respond for so long. I was thinking about how to show it. I see what you mean and I think I managed to show it, but I have further question. Am I right that we don't need to show that GL(n,R) where R is Reals,Complex or H is open subset of M(n,R) to show that GL(n,R) forms a topological group. We only need this further, for defining manifold structure.

Answer (score 3):

The classical group $GL_n(\mathbb{H})$ is in fact a Lie group, hence also a topological group. We have $$\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{H}) = \{g \in \mathrm{GL}(2n, \mathbb{C})|Jg = \overline{g}J, \mathrm{det}( g) \ne 0\} \equiv \mathrm{U}^*(2n),$$
which is a Lie group, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_group#GL.28n.2C_H.29_and_SL.28n.2C_H.29).

Comment: I don't see where you got this in the article. What is $J$? What do you mean by $\overline g$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom J is defined in the article as usual by $J_n$, see a few lines above the section "$GL(n,\mathbb{H})$ and $SL(n,\mathbb{H})$", i.e., in the section *Quaternionic case*.